# ArrayOutOfIndexException android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an arrayoutofindexexception in my code below:

```
    ImageView[] bObject = new ImageView[9];

    private void getCorrectObject() {

    List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    objects.add(1);
    objects.add(2);
    objects.add(3);
    objects.add(4);
    objects.add(5);
    objects.add(6);
    objects.add(7);
    objects.add(8);
    objects.add(9);

    Collections.shuffle(objects);
    int correctObject =  objects.get(0);
    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(correctObject));

            bObject[correctObject + 1].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object1);
    bObject[correctObject + 1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                goToNextQuestion();
            }
        });
            }


           //TODO initControls
private void initControls() {

    bObject[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject1Stage1_4);
    bObject[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject2Stage1_4);
    bObject[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject3Stage1_4);
    bObject[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject4Stage1_4);
    bObject[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject5Stage1_4);
    bObject[4].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[5] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject6Stage1_4);
    bObject[5].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[6] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject7Stage1_4);
    bObject[6].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[7] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject8Stage1_4);
    bObject[7].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);
    bObject[8] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bObject9Stage1_4);
    bObject[8].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object2);

            for (ImageView bObj  : bObject) {
                   bObj.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
```

I'm getting an error in this line:

```
        bObject[correctObject + 1].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object1);
```

I don't know what's wrong with this. If you find what's wrong, any help is truly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are zero based. Here the values used exceed the bounds of the array `bObject`. Use

Add values to the `List` starting from `0`:

```
objects.add(0);
...
objects.add(8);
```

and use:

```
bObject[correctObject].setImageResource(...);
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
for (int i=0; i < bObject.length; i++)
   objects.add(i);
}
```

This will remove the need to hard code index values.

To eliminate the `objects` index `List` completely, [Random#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) can be used, for example:

```
bObject[random.nextInt(bObject.length)].setImageResource(...);
```

Comment: Okay so what happens to the correctObject? Since I set it equal to objects(0);?

Comment: There is no issue. After the shuffle you are retrieving the value at index `0`. Once the values are with the index range an `ArrayOutOfIndexException` will not occur

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0 based in Java-  the first index is 0.  So bObject has valid range of 0...8.  The value of correctObject will be random 1...9.  Adding 1 to it will bring 2...10.  So if you get a 9 or 10 you're accessing out of range of the array.  A 20% chance you'll do that and crash.

You probably wanted to subtract 1, not add it.

Answer (score 0):

You should say
  bObject[correctObject - 1].setImageResource(R.drawable.stage1_4_object1);

because correctobject value could be 9 and max index you could give to bObject is 8.